# How to assign cell value from a filtered search?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to subtract dates using do while loop within the filtered criteria but I do not know how to get the cell of the filtered rows.

I tried using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

```
Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    k = 8
    Dim holder As Long
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$9:$G$332").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
        "AP"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$O$9:$O$332").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
        "Released"

    Do While 79 > i


        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
        ' ** Cells(k,"S") ** Is the problem
        holder = Cells(k, "S").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]-RC[-11]"


    Loop
```

I expect the output would subtract only within the filtered criteria.

Comment: `S` represents a Column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
k = 8

Dim holder As Long

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$S$332").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="AP"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$S$332").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="Released"

Do While 79 > i


    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1

    If Not Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("S" & k), ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$S$332").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Is Nothing Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("S" & k).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]-RC[-11]"

    End If

Loop
```

Comment: it did followed the criteria but it stops at cell value ("s",87). I'm trying to get all 79 rows that match with the criteria not until it reached a cell count of 79 from 9-87.

Comment: `Cells("S",87)`  is wrong Method, either pass on `Range("S" , 87)` or `Cells(19,87)`

Comment: i used `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(9, "S"), Cells(332, "S")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]-RC[-11]"` and I got the desired result. I will optimize this code again after a finished all other requirement thanks man :) +1